# How to write to a locked file in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writting in a file that has the .csv extension . The function that writes in the file is called from a timer that checks continuosly some conditions and updates the file. However, if the user decides to open that file while the timer is running I will obviously get an exception.

Is there a possibility to avoid this and update the file so that the user will see the updated file when reopens the file ?

EDIT:

```
   Timer=new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                       //Here I check the conditions

                       checkConditions();
                       if(checkConditions())
                       {     
                           writeInFile();
                       }
                     }
             }
      }
```

EDIT(2):

```
  public void writeInFile()
        {
        File firstFile=new File("file location");
        BufferedWriter out_firstFile = null;
        FileWriter firstFileStream;
        firstFileStream= new FileWriter(firstFile, false);

out_firstFile = new BufferedWriter(firstFileStream);
        out_firstFile.write("Here I write something :) ");
        out_firstFile.close(); 

        }
```

Comment: can you post the code of the timer at least? ;)

Comment: I've added the timer code :)

Comment: The user will see the last saved version of this file. If you are using a buffered version this might not coincide with the most updated version though.

Comment: make sure you open and close the file within the same iteration of the timer.

Comment: I've edited with writeInFile() function where I close the file everytime

Comment: You need a buffer. If exception occurs write the data in the buffer instead (in the `catch` block). When you get access to the file write your data AND the buffer.

Comment: As a side note `if(checkConditions==true)` is redundant. `if(checkConditions)` is enough (better yet is `if(checkConditions())` )

Comment: It was an example only...you can consider checkConditions a global variable that can be setted true or false by the checkConditions() function :) ,

Comment: That's exactly why I pointed it out. If the variable `chackConditions` is used only there it is useless, you can directly check the method `if(checkConditions())`. Still, this is not strictly an error, just code review :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your statement "However, if the user decides to open that file while the timer is running I will obviously get a FileNotFound exception." is absolutely not obvious.

What do you call "open the file". If user opens file using text editor or one of the viewing tools it depends on the tool. For example either `less` of Unix or Notepad from MS Windows just read the file and do not even lock it. Howerver other tools can lock the file, so you indeed will not be able to write to it, but I think that the exception will be different.

So, I'd change your question to the following "How to write to locked file?". 
And the short answer is "you cannot write to the locked file."
The solution that I can suggest is to implement re-try mechanism. If for example you cannot write to file because it is locked at the moment, write your content to temporary file and try again, and again ... and again until you succeed.